# transform data frame to another form

Tags: r

I'm new in [r]. And recently i'm stuck in how to perform operation in data.frame.
Now I have a data.frame called frame. And I want to transform it to another form.

```
> frame
         A      B  Freq total
1        0      0   75   110
2        1      0   21   110
3        0      1    8   110
4        1      1    6   110
```

the expected form is:

```
> frame(B=1)
         A    Freq total
1        0      8   83
2        1      6   27
```

Can anyone give some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It's best to explain in words what you want, not just to show the input and output.

Comment: Do you want to get the total values of A that are 0, the total values of B that are 0, and the same for A and B but with 1?  It seems like there's an inconsistency in the transformation you have in your expected form.

Comment: sorry. I forget to say that B=1

Answer (score 2):

One option would be using `dplyr`.  We group by 'A', and create a new column 'total' as the `sum` of "Freq", `filter` the rows where 'B' = 1, and `select` all other columns except 'B'

```
library(dplyr)
frame %>% 
     group_by(A) %>% 
     mutate(total= sum(Freq)) %>%
     filter(B==1)%>%
     select(-B)
#  A Freq total
#1 0    8    83
#2 1    6    27
```

Or using `data.table`, we convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT(frame)` or we can do `as.data.table(frame)`), create a new column `total` as the `sum` of 'Freq', grouped by 'A', subset the rows with B=1, and remove the 'B' column by assigning it to NULL.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(frame)[, total:= sum(Freq), A][B==1][,B:=NULL]
#   A Freq total
#1: 0    8    83
#2: 1    6    27
```

Or using `base R`, we create the 'total' using `transform/ave` and then `subset` the rows that are 1 for 'B'.

```
subset(transform(frame, total=ave(Freq, A, FUN=sum)), B==1, select=-B)
#   A Freq total
#3 0    8    83
#4 1    6    27
```

Comment: what's the setDT mean?

Comment: @Program added some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using functions in the base package - `aggregate()` and `merge()`.

```
frame <- read.table(header = T, text = "
A      B  Freq total
1        0      0   75   110
2        1      0   21   110
3        0      1    8   110
4        1      1    6   110")

# obtain sum by column A
frame1 <- aggregate(frame$Freq, by = list(frame$A), sum)
names(frame1) <- c("A", "total")

# merge Freq
frame2 <- merge(frame1, frame[frame$B == 1, c(1,3)], by="A")
#  A total Freq
#1 0    83    8
#2 1    27    6
```